# Why does PySpin.CameraList().GetSize() return zero devices?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, pyspin

Why does the following code return a cameralist with a device via `PySpin.System()` class and not via `PySpin.CameraList()` class?

The return value may differ depending on how many cameras you've attached from the manufacturer.

```py
import PySpin

system = PySpin.System.GetInstance()

cam_list = system.GetCameras()

numCams  = cam_list.GetSize()                 # return value >= 1

numCams2  = PySpin.CameraList().GetSize()     # return value  = 0 

print ("No. of cams: %s - %s" % (numCams, numCams2))
```

Result:

> No. of cams: 1 - 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**class PySpin.System(*args, **kwargs):**

Here the system object `GetCameras()` is used to retrieve the list of interfaces and cameras available on your OS.
This only works if the static systempointer `GetInstance()` is used. Then the devices are loaded into the CameraList()
 and therefor not empty.

**class PySpin.CameraList(*args):**

Used to hold a list of camera objects and does not retrieve it by itself.

Hence, `numCams = len(system.GetCameras())` will also work to get the No. of devices.